# Join different tables based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

```
create table [premiumuser] (user_id int, name nvarchar(50));
create table [liteuser] (user_id int, name nvarchar(50));
create table [feature] (id nvarchar(50), user_id int, userkey int);

insert into [premiumuser] select 1, 'stephen';
insert into [premiumuser] select 2, 'roger';

insert into [liteuser] select 1, 'apollo';
insert into [liteuser] select 2, 'venus';

insert into feature select 'Upload content', 1, 1;
insert into feature select 'Create account', 1, 0;
insert into feature select 'View content', 2, 0;
```

I would like to see data from **feature** table and instead of `userid` i want the `username`.
The catch here is if `userkey` is 0, get the `username` from **liteuser** table, else from **premiumuser** table.
Data should be like

```
'Upload content', 'stephen', 1
'Create account', 'apollo', 0
'View content', 'venus', 0
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    f.id,
        case when userkey=0 then l.name else p.name end as username
from [feature] f
    left join [liteuser] l on l.user_id = f.user_id
    left join [premium user] p on p.user_id = f.user_id
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT f.id
, (CASE WHEN f.userkey = 0 THEN l.name ELSE p.name END) AS name
, f.userkey
FROM feature f
LEFT JOIN liteuser l on f.user_id = l.user_id
LEFT JOIN premiumuser p on p.user_id = l.user_id
```

I suggest using left joins over inner joins, as you seem to be asking about all users associated with a given feature. This way, features with no associated users will have NULL as the name. Additionally, using two inner joins against the user tables will only return only those features which have an entry for the same user in both the premium and lite tables.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know about [JOINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) condition.

```
SELECT f.id , CASE userkey WHEN 0 then l.name ELSE p.name END,f.userkey
FROM feature f
INNER JOIN liteuser
     ON f.user_id=l.user_id
INNER JOIN premiumuser p
     ON f.user_id=p.user_id
```

EDIT :

As suggested by Pieter Geerkens , a LEFT JOIN may be required by you.
LEFT JOIN results in retrieving matching rows from both tables PLUS non matching rows from 
table situated on leftside of join . The rows from rightside table are filled with NULL value.

INNER JOIN only gives rows having matching value in joining field.

Comment: True: better correct, as I think the OP needs a LEFT JOIN here, as only one will exist at a time I believe.

Comment: @mhasan Inner joins against the user tables means that results will only return when the same user id is present in all three tables. Your code will work for the sample data in the question, but I doubt that production data for these schema would have duplicate user records in both user tables.